# Python Flask - TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Tags: python, flask

I'm building a simple web-app in Python Flask but when I am trying to submit the form, I am getting this error message -

"TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)"

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash, redirect, url_for, session, logging
from data import Articles
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
from wtforms import Form, StringField, TextAreaField, PasswordField, validators
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt

app = Flask(__name__)

# Config MySQL
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_PORT'] = '8889'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = '123456'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'myflaskapp'
app.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS'] = 'DictCursor'

#init MYSQL
mysql = MySQL(app)

Articles = Articles()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')

@app.route('/articles')
def articles():
    return render_template('articles.html', articles = Articles)

@app.route('/article/<string:id>')
def article(id):
    return render_template('article.html', id = id)

class RegisterForm(Form):
    name = StringField('Name', [validators.Length(min=1, max=50)])
    username = StringField('Username', [validators.Length(min=4, max=25)])
    email = StringField('Email', [validators.Length(min=6, max=50)])
    password = PasswordField('New Password', [
            validators.DataRequired(),
            validators.EqualTo('confirm', message='Passwords must match')
        ])
    confirm = PasswordField('Repeat Password')

@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegisterForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        name = form.name.data
        email = form.email.data
        username = form.username.data
        password = sha256_crypt.encrypt(str(form.password.data))

        # Create cursor
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

        # Execute query
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO users(name, email, username, password) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)", (name, email, username, password))

        # Commit to DB
        mysql.connection.commit()

        #  Close connection
        cur.close()

        flash('You are now registered and can log in', 'success')

        return redirect(url_for('login'))

    return render_template('register.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = 'secret123'
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Traceback (most recent call last)

```
File "C:\Users\Harsh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\Harsh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Harsh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Harsh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Harsh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Harsh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Harsh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Harsh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Harsh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Harsh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Harsh\Desktop\Projects\py\myflaskapp\app.py", line 58, in register
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
  File "C:\Users\Harsh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask_mysqldb\__init__.py", line 94, in connection
    ctx.mysql_db = self.connect
  File "C:\Users\Harsh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask_mysqldb\__init__.py", line 81, in connect
    return MySQLdb.connect(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Harsh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 86, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Harsh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 204, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

I am not sure why this is happening, can anyone guide me on this please. I looked at the other solutions on here, but they didn't really work for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In config parameters PORT must be an Integer 
you are here passing it in string

```
#Config MySQL
app.config['MYSQL_PORT'] = '8889' ##pass 8889 instead of '8889'
```