# _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'admin.users' doesn't exist")

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am trying to make simple login app with flask using mysql connection  but i get **TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)** in the web browser when i run the login function

and this is the code :

```
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session, abort
import os
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
from wtforms import Form, StringField, TextAreaField, PasswordField, validators
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt
from functools import wraps

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'admin'
app.config['MYSQL_PORT'] = 3306
app.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS'] = 'DictCursor'
# init MYSQL
mysql = MySQL(app)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        return render_template('login.html')
    else:
        return "Hello Boss!"

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def do_admin_login():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

    POST_USERNAME = str(request.form['username'])
    POST_PASSWORD = str(request.form['password'])

    result = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s", [POST_USERNAME])


    if result:
        session['logged_in'] = True
        cur.close()     
    else:
        flash('wrong password!')
    return home()

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session['logged_in']=False
    return home()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.secret_key = os.urandom(12)
    app.run(debug=True)
```

error in the image

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Flask - TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43756914/python-flask-typeerror-an-integer-is-required-got-type-str)

Comment: MySQL port address should be an integer: ```app.config['MYSQL_PORT'] = 5000```

Comment: i have changed that , i got a different error

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it ..at first i was using the wrong port number for mysql ,i checked the right one one from the xampp wizard window..
secondly, i had a wrong table name